# How to extend my desktop to a second connected screen?

Tags: multi-monitor, desktop, laptop

I connected a screen to my laptop, and it's blank. How do I extend my desktop to this screen?

Comment: Although that's technically done with the operating system's cooperation, Linux follows the standard set by makers, who have done two things: engraved an icon on `F5` to indicate that the function key is `Fn+F5` (on many, but not all, laptops), and provided a windows driver. So if all you want to know is the key combination, this question is off-topic. But if you also want other methods such as a command line or GUI application, the question is on-topic.

Answer (score 10):

Right now I am answering this with my notebook connected to a monitor. To have my desktop extended I use `xrandr` and its graphical interface `ARandR`, both of them working pretty well.

Indeed, I have a script which I execute every time I log to my notebook having the screen attached to it:

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1280x800 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output VGA1 --mode 1440x900 --pos 1280x0 --rotate normal --output HDMI1 --off
```

To understand it, first of all you must see that it references three `outputs`: **LVDS1** which is the laptop screen; **VGA1** which is my external monitor; and **HDMI1** which is disabled (option `--off` right after it) because I don't have any monitor attached to that port.

You can get the list of outputs available with:

```
xrandr -q
```

Following every `output` are some parameters that set specific features for them:

- `mode`: sets the resolution of the output.
- `pos`: which sets the position of the output relative to the top left corner of the composed desktop.
- `rotate`: which sets the rotation you want for the output.

I have an Intel graphics adapter. In the case of nVidia, they have an application to select `TwinView`, for example.

Comment: tl;dr :) Can you summarize why your answer is better than Fn-F5?

Comment: Simple: because not always Fn-F5 works, and with the method I described you can position just as you need the screens you are using.   
I have a link to that script in my desktop, so that when I have the external monitor attached to my laptop, I can easily set up the screens (without it, the system just enables the external monitor and shuts off the one of the laptop).

Answer (score 2):

(Let me treat this Q&A as a memo to my future self)

The easiest way I found with simply press the "extend desktop" button - Function F5.

Answer (score 2):

For example in KDE4 you run System Settings, and in Display settings you select to extend monitor (and also at which side -- left or right -- you would like to "place" the second monitor). 100% straightforward.